# Problem with generic type of object with functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have some number of functions, two for example. They have one argument each, but of a different type. All functions written in object `functionsList` with `as const` type.

```js
interface ArgsA {
    a: string
    b: number
}

function fnA(args: ArgsA): number {
    return 5
}

interface ArgsB {
    c: string
    d: number
}

function fnB(args: ArgsB): number {
    return 5
}

const functionsList = {
    fnA,
    fnB,
} as const
```

Next i have types `FnName` and generic `FnArgs`, which extracting names of entries and argument type of function from the object

```js
type FnName = keyof typeof functionsList
type FnArgs<TName extends FnName> = Parameters<(typeof functionsList)[TName]>[0]
```

Last i have generic type `CallObj`, which one describe argument for function `call`. It doesn't change anything, only connects the previous types. A function simply calls another function from an object by name with the given arguments

```js
type CallObj<TName extends FnName> = {
    name: TName
    args: FnArgs<TName>
}

function call<TName extends FnName>(obj: CallObj<TName>): void {
    console.log(functionsList[obj.name](obj.args))
}
```

Generic `CallObj` works fine, everything works but in function i have type error

```js
function call<TName extends FnName>(obj: CallObj<TName>): void {
    console.log(functionsList[obj.name](obj.args))
//                                      -------- Type error here
// Argument of type 'ArgsA | ArgsB' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArgsA & ArgsB'.
//    Type 'ArgsA' is not assignable to type 'ArgsA & ArgsB'.
//       Type 'ArgsA' is missing the following properties from type 'ArgsB': c, d
}
```

I'm understand why it appears. Typescript doesn't know which one function called at `functionsList[obj.name]` and creates a type using the `&` operator, which expecting arguments that match all functions. Is there any way to solve this problem?

I do not know if this can be solved by fixing the types, so I only thought about type defenders, but did not come up with one.

Of course, I can ignore the problem by this and it doesn't cause me problems, but I wonder if there is a solution

```js
functionsList[obj.name](obj.args as any)
(functionsList[obj.name] as any)(obj.args)
// @ts-ignore
functionsList[obj.name](obj.args)
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mbaB3N) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is unable to handle the "correlated union types" described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), however, there is a suggested refactor described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), which considers moving to generics. First, we will need some map type that will hold the accepted arguments of the functions and their return type:

```
type TypeMap = {
  fnA: { args: ArgsA; return: number };
  fnB: { args: ArgsB; return: number };
};
```

Now, using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) we need to redefine the `functionsList`:

```
// const functionsList: {
//   fnA: (args: ArgsA) => number;
//   fnB: (args: ArgsB) => number;
// }
const functionsList: {
  [K in keyof TypeMap]: (args: TypeMap[K]['args']) => TypeMap[K]['return'];
} = {
  fnA,
  fnB,
};
```

Next, we will need to create a generic mapped type that will accept the name of the function and return the arguments that `call` should accept:

```
type FnArgs<TName extends keyof TypeMap = keyof TypeMap> = {
  [K in TName]: {
    name: K;
    args: TypeMap[K]['args'];
  };
}[TName];
```

Testing:

```
function call<TName extends keyof TypeMap>(obj: FnArgs<TName>): void {
  console.log(functionsList[obj.name](obj.args)); // no error
}
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJQOYGdXIN4BQyxycAXMlmFKBgNxEkBGFIArgLZPQMC+BBGGxAIwwAPYhkMEKgAUcTFgrpsqAJStO3KPkbEoEMGyhSArHwGhIsRClVYAQnpLIEFKjRD19yACZaXDwE-ILCohJSMo4KSipKjprI7EG6hK6GxqbIFiECYACeAA4oACrFEACycEXIALwuJDKoFHikcWhKqHTImSYggTrIvAyu0a3t2PHYjj19poPQw3wMBAiSVNLhYhsAMsBUrb4A2gDSyKDIANYQBeIwyOUl1UUAuhSxU48VL2evxwByRTYAGvdT1AB832eNT+gPmIFBfHqjWIzQANL5opiRvkKsgAGKyJQAHlKADk4BwUBAAB6QEB+LDXW73aFVGoom53B5PDlFKENdIkM4XKQUqkQd6o1zJSUUU6jWXEYHKdm-U7-IFKJG+XG8Y4S6mvVZCEQ7KQIOAAG2tZMp1OQdIZTJZPPVNQhcnETAAVhQiQ57ZKIUkAG7iYB+GXrEBYcTWiAAOmt4gwcjNET2BzAxx9vqTIElr29fqTqvU6ksQA)